# Issues with JList Calculation (CVE)?

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to get a running total price of all the elements within my Jlist as they are being added however just can't seem to get it to work. I've tried to provide the classes necessary to be able to reproduce my problem for greater clarity on what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

-Main GUI

```
public class PaymentSystemGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JLabel priceLabel;
    private JLabel totalLabel;
    private JTextField totalField;
    private JButton scanBtn;
    private JList checkoutList;
    private JScrollPane jScrollCheckout;
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JButton removeBtn;
    private JButton addBtn;
    private JTextField priceField;
    private JTextField barcodeField;
    private JLabel barcodeLabel;
    private JTextField itemNameField;
    private JLabel jItemName;
    private JLabel editorLabel;
    private JScrollPane checkScrollPane;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JMenuItem exitButton;
    private JMenu StartButton;
    private JMenuBar MainMenBar;
    private DefaultListModel Inventory = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultListModel checkoutBasket = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList productList;
    private InventoryList stockInst;
    private JFileChooser chooser;
    private File saveFile;
    private boolean changesMade;

    /**
     * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PaymentSystemGUI inst = new PaymentSystemGUI();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public PaymentSystemGUI() {
        super();
        initGUI();

        stockInst = new InventoryList();


        productList.setModel(stockInst);
        checkoutList.setModel(checkoutBasket);

    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(245, 245, 245));
            this.setEnabled(true);
            {
                MainMenBar = new JMenuBar();
                setJMenuBar(MainMenBar);
                {
                    StartButton = new JMenu();
                    MainMenBar.add(StartButton);
                    StartButton.setText("File");
                    {
                        exitButton = new JMenuItem();
                        StartButton.add(exitButton);
                        exitButton.setText("Exit");
                        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }

                        );

                    }

                }


                {
                    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
                    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
                    jScrollPane1.setBounds(31, 84, 275, 323);
                    jScrollPane1.setAlignmentY(0.4f);
                    {
                        ListModel stockListModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                                new String[] { "Item One", "Item Two" });
                        productList = new JList();
                        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(productList);
                        BorderLayout stockListLayout = new BorderLayout();
                        productList.setLayout(stockListLayout);
                        productList.setBounds(25, 92, 269, 330);
                        productList.setAlignmentX(0.4f);
                        productList.setModel(stockListModel);
                    }
                }
                {
                    editorLabel = new JLabel();
                    getContentPane().add(editorLabel);
                    editorLabel.setText("INVENTORY");
                    editorLabel.setBounds(121, 56, 88, 16);
                }
                {
                    jItemName = new JLabel();
                    getContentPane().add(jItemName);
                    jItemName.setText("Item Name");
                    jItemName.setBounds(31, 432, 61, 16);
                }
                {
                    itemNameField = new JTextField();
                    getContentPane().add(itemNameField);
                    itemNameField.setBounds(127, 426, 130, 28);
                }
                {
                    barcodeLabel = new JLabel();
                    getContentPane().add(barcodeLabel);
                    barcodeLabel.setText("Barcode Number");
                    barcodeLabel.setBounds(27, 476, 94, 16);
                }
                {
                    barcodeField = new JTextField();
                    getContentPane().add(barcodeField);
                    barcodeField.setBounds(127, 470, 130, 28);
                }
                {
                    priceLabel = new JLabel();
                    getContentPane().add(priceLabel);
                    priceLabel.setText("Price of Item");
                    priceLabel.setBounds(33, 521, 68, 16);
                }
                {
                    priceField = new JTextField();
                    getContentPane().add(priceField);
                    priceField.setBounds(127, 515, 130, 28);
                }
                {
                    addBtn = new JButton();
                    getContentPane().add(addBtn);
                    addBtn.setText("Add");
                    addBtn.setBounds(53, 560, 83, 28);

                }
                addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evta) {
                        addButtonPressed();
                    }
                });
                {
                    removeBtn = new JButton();
                    getContentPane().add(removeBtn);
                    removeBtn.setText("Remove");
                    removeBtn.setBounds(148, 560, 83, 28);
                    removeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            removeButtonPressed();
                        }
                    });

                }
                {
                    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
                    getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
                    jLabel1.setText("CHECKOUT");
                    jLabel1.setBounds(480, 79, 68, 16);
                }
                {
                    jScrollCheckout = new JScrollPane();
                    getContentPane().add(jScrollCheckout);
                    jScrollCheckout.setBounds(395, 107, 248, 323);
                    {
                        ListModel checkoutListModel = 
                                new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                                        new String[] { "Item One", "Item Two" });
                        checkoutList = new JList();
                        jScrollCheckout.setViewportView(checkoutList);
                        checkoutList.setModel(checkoutListModel);
                    }
                }
                {
                    scanBtn = new JButton();
                    getContentPane().add(scanBtn);
                    scanBtn.setText("Scan Item into Checkout");
                    scanBtn.setBounds(59, 613, 161, 28);
                    scanBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            checkoutBasket.addElement(productList.getSelectedValue());
                              double totalAddedValue = 0.00;
                              double oldCheckoutValue   = 0.00;

                              //Iterate to get the price of the new items.
                              for (int i = 1; i < productList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
                                InventItem item = (InventItem) productList.getModel().getElementAt(i);
                                totalAddedValue += Double.parseDouble(item.getPrice());
                              }

                              //Set total price value as an addition to cart total field.

                              //cartTotalField must be accessible here.
                              String checkoutField = totalField.getText();

                              //Check that cartTextField already contains a value.
                              if(checkoutField != null && !checkoutField.isEmpty())
                              {
                                oldCheckoutValue = Double.parseDouble(checkoutField);
                              }

                              totalField.setText(String.valueOf(oldCheckoutValue  + totalAddedValue));
                              checkoutBasket.addElement(productList);
                            }
                        });
                }
                {
                    totalField = new JTextField();
                    getContentPane().add(totalField);
                    totalField.setBounds(503, 442, 115, 28);
                    totalField.setEditable(false);
                }
                {
                    totalLabel = new JLabel();
                    getContentPane().add(totalLabel);
                    totalLabel.setText("Total Cost of Items");
                    totalLabel.setBounds(367, 448, 124, 16);
                }

                pack();
                this.setSize(818, 730);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void loadMenuItemAction() {
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("itemdata.dat");
            ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            stockInst = (InventoryList)oIn.readObject();
            productList.setModel(stockInst);
            oIn.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to read file");
        System.out.println("Error : " + e);
    }


    }

    private void clearAllTextFields() {
        barcodeField.setText("");
        itemNameField.setText("");
        priceField.setText("");
    }


    private void removeButtonPressed() {
        int selectedIndex = productList.getSelectedIndex();

        if (selectedIndex == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select An Item to Remove");
        } else {
            InventItem toGo = (InventItem)stockInst.getElementAt(selectedIndex);
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Do you really want to remove the item from the cart ? : " + toGo,
                    "Delete Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) 
                    == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                stockInst.removeItem(toGo.getID());
                clearAllTextFields();
                productList.clearSelection();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addButtonPressed() {
        String newbarcode = barcodeField.getText();
        String newitemName = itemNameField.getText();
        String newprice = priceField.getText();

        if (newbarcode.equals("") || newitemName.equals("") || newprice.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Enter Full Details");
        } else {
            stockInst.addInventItem(newbarcode, newitemName, newprice);
            InventItem newBasket = stockInst.findItemByName(newbarcode);
            productList.setSelectedValue(newBasket, true);
            clearAllTextFields();
        }
    }

}
```

-InventoryList

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class InventoryList extends DefaultListModel {
    public InventoryList(){
        super();
    }

    public void addInventItem(String idNo, String itemName, String total){
        super.addElement(new InventItem(idNo, itemName, total));
    }

    public InventItem findItemByName(String name){
        InventItem temp;
        int indexLocation = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
            temp = (InventItem)super.elementAt(i);
            if (temp.getItemName().equals(name)){
                indexLocation = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (indexLocation == -1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (InventItem)super.elementAt(indexLocation);
        }
    }


    public InventItem findItemByBarcode(String id){
        InventItem temp;
        int indexLocation = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
            temp = (InventItem)super.elementAt(i);
            if (temp.getID().equals(id)){
                indexLocation = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (indexLocation == -1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (InventItem)super.elementAt(indexLocation);
        }        
    }

    public void removeItem(String id){
        InventItem empToGo = this.findItemByBarcode(id);
        super.removeElement(empToGo);
    }
}
```

InventoryItem

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class InventItem implements Serializable {

    private String idnum;
    private String itemName;
    private String cost;

    public InventItem() {

    }

    public InventItem (String barno, String in, String price) {
            idnum = barno;
            itemName = in;
            cost = price;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return idnum;
    }

    public String getItemName(){
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setitemName(String itemName){
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

    public String getPrice(){
        return cost;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return idnum + ": " + itemName + ", £ " + cost;

    }


}
```

Comment: 1) The letter "M" in MCVE stands for "minimal", and your code is not that. 2) You're still adding your JList itself to the checkout basket, `checkoutBasket.addElement(productList);`, despite getting recommendations in at least 2 of your previous similar questions not to do this. Why are you still doing this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - 1) Fair point. 2) I'm a beginner and don't quite know how to change my code to add a single element from the list.

Comment: `I'm a beginner and don't quite know how to change my code to add a single element from the list.` - so ask a specific question that says. "how do I copy an element from a JList to another JList?". Don't title your question with "JLIst Calculation" which means nothing to anybody. Tell us what the exact problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: For a proper MCVE you create a simple frame with two JLists. One JLIst is preloaded with some default items. The second is empty. Then you create a "Copy" button to copy one item to the other. We don't care about your real application, only the "concept" that you are tying to learn. Once you learn the simple concept you apply the knowledge to your real application.

Comment: @user4702874, Why on earth would you accept my answer and then just repeat the question under another user id? If there is something about the answer you don't understand `ask a specific question`!!! From your other question you ask `why does it print the total value of ALL the items in the products list` well why are you looping through the product list? Should you not be looping through the checkout basket list??? Of course you still need to add the items to the check out basket list. Why have you not created the loop to copy the items to the check basket???

Comment: Why is your other code not in the form of a MCVE? You say you are a beginner but you refuse to listen to the suggestions provided. I gave you the basis of an MCVE. All you need to do is add about 4 lines of code to create the loop and add each item individually. Once you master this step you can then change the data to store "Integer" objects in the JList. Then when you copy the Integer values you can then add logic to total the value of the Integer object copied. Once you master this, the last step is to take the knowledge and apply it to your real code. There are no shortcuts to learning!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm a beginner and don't quite know how to change my code to add a single element from the list.

Read the `List` API and you will find methods like:

1. size()
2. get(...)

So you create a loop that loops from 0 to the number of elements. Inside the loop you get the element from the List and add it to the model of the checkoutBasket JList.

Here is the basics of an `MCVE` to get you started. All you need to do is add the code for the actionPerformed() method to copy the selected item(s):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    JList<String> left;
    JList<String> right;
    JLabel total;


    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // change this to store Integer objects
        String[] data = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "four", "six", "seven" };
        left = new JList<String>(data);
        add(new JScrollPane(left), BorderLayout.WEST);

        right = new JList<String>( new DefaultListModel<String>() );
        add(new JScrollPane(right), BorderLayout.EAST);

        JButton button = new JButton( "Copy" );
        add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>)right.getModel();
                List<String> selected = left.getSelectedValuesList();

                for (String item: selected)
                    model.addElement( item );

                // add code here to loop through right list and total the Integer items

                total.setText("Selected total is ?");
            }
        });

        total = new JLabel("Selected total is 0");
        add(total, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SSCCE() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you have a problem then delete your original code and post the MCVE showing what you have tried based on the information in this answer. Don't create a new posting.

Edit:

My original answer talked about copying the data from the DefaultListModel. However, your code is using the `JList.getSelectedValuesList()` method to get a `List` of selected items. Each of these items needs to be copied from the `List` to the `ListModel` of the `JList`. I updated my answer to reflect this part of your code. I even wrote the code to show you how to copy the items from the list.

So now your next step is to calculate the a total of the items in the "right" JLIst (ie, your checkout basked). In order to do this, you need to change the data in the "left" list to be "Integer" Objects. So now when you copy the Integer objects yo9u can then iterate through the JList and calculate a total value. If you have problems, then any code you post should be based on this MVCE and NOT your real program.

Comment: Next, 1) avoid null layouts as they look terrible on all other platforms and are very difficult to maintain or enhance, 2) Avoid needless extra curly brace blocks that appear present in the code for no reason but to confuse, 3) Try to re-factor code to avoid huge "god" classes and to make debugging and enhancing easier. 1+ for this answer and for your patience!

Comment: Re-asked with a *new* user-name here: [How to alter this method to loop over items in my Jlist and calculate total](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269739/how-to-alter-this-method-to-loop-over-items-in-my-jlist-and-calculate-total)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, unbelievable!!! What does it take to get through to this guy?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, unbelievable, I specifically asked him not to create a new posting.